# Custom query Spring Data JPA + REST

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my data base, I have a table "CITA" with this attributes: id, fecha_hora, descripcion, id_empleado, id_cliente.

Too, I have a Spring JPA Repository:

```
public interface CitaRepository extends JpaRepository<Cita, Long> {...}
```

And **I need this query**:

`"SELECT id_empleado, count(id) from Cita GROUP BY id_empleado ORDER BY fecha_hora"`

My problem is that I don't know where I should place it to return me something like Map

Because it don't work:

```
@Query("SELECT id_empleado, count(id) from Cita GROUP BY id_empleado ORDER BY fecha_hora")
  Map<Integer,Integer> estadisticas();
```

**EDIT**

I have an error if I try to call estadisticas() from my REST controller.

This is my **REST controller**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class CitaResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CitaResource.class);

    @Inject
    private CitaRepository citaRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/citas/estadisticas",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<CitaDTO> estadisticas() {
    return citaRepository.estadisticas();
}
```

This is my **JPA repository**:

```
public interface CitaRepository extends JpaRepository<Cita, Long> {

@Query("SELECT new com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.dto.CitaDTO(c.empleado_id, count(c)) from Cita c GROUP BY c.empleado_id ORDER BY c.fecha_hora")
    List<CitaDTO> estadisticas();

}
```

This is my **DTO class**:

```
package com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.dto;

public class CitaDTO {

    private int empleado_id;
    private long count;

    public CitaDTO(int empleado_id, long count) {
        this.empleado_id = empleado_id;
        this.count = count;
    }
   //get & set
}
```

This is my **entity Cita**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CITA")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Cita implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "fecha_hora", nullable = false)
    private DateTime fecha_hora;

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Servicio> servicios = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    private Empleado empleado;
}
```

I have this errors:

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'citaResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.raquel.tfg.repository.CitaRepository com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.CitaResource.citaRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'citaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.raquel.tfg.repository.CitaRepository.estadisticas()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.raquel.tfg.Application.main(Application.java:56) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.raquel.tfg.repository.CitaRepository com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.CitaResource.citaRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'citaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.raquel.tfg.repository.CitaRepository.estadisticas()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'citaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.raquel.tfg.repository.CitaRepository.estadisticas()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.raquel.tfg.repository.CitaRepository.estadisticas()!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:57) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:51) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:137) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:202) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: empleado_id of: com.raquel.tfg.domain.Cita [SELECT new com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.dto.CitaDTO(c.empleado_id, count(c)) from com.raquel.tfg.domain.Cita c GROUP BY c.empleado_id ORDER BY c.fecha_hora]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: empleado_id of: com.raquel.tfg.domain.Cita [SELECT new com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.dto.CitaDTO(c.empleado_id, count(c)) from com.raquel.tfg.domain.Cita c GROUP BY c.empleado_id ORDER BY c.fecha_hora]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: empleado_id of: com.raquel.tfg.domain.Cita
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:652) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveSelectExpression(DotNode.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolveSelectExpression(HqlSqlWalker.java:958) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2257) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.constructor(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2607) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2324) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2194) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1476) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:573) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1457) of a similar question.

Comment: Sorry: but how do you expect that someone can help you with "I have an error"? - We need an discription for the error, stacktrace, ....

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner and it is the first time that I ask something... But I hope you can help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JPA way would to use the `Select new` query. You need a Java class (not a mapped JPA Entity) - often called a DTO, that contains the two fields `empleadoId` `count` and a constructor that take them

```
package com.example
public class Dto {
   private int empleadoId;
   private long count;

   public Dto(int empleadoId, long count) {
       this.empleadoId = empleadoId;
       this.count = count;
   }
   //getter and setter
}
```

then you can write this repository method:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.Dto(c.id_empleado, count(c)) " +
       "from Cita c GROUP BY c.id_empleado ORDER BY c.fecha_hora")
Map<Integer,Integer> statistics();
```

*Note: Take care that `c.id_empleado` snf `c.fecha_hora` must match the name of the field, not the column*

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast, but although I applied your solution, now I have another problem. I edited the question.

Comment: @r.diazgoz: your probelm `could not resolve property: empleado_id of: com.raquel.tfg.domain.Cita`  - is what I have wirtten in italic: you need write the name of the java fields  of your `Cita` class (that are mapped to the columns) in the query, but not the name of the columns! (I can to write the query with the correct names, because you have not posted the Cita class)

Comment: SOLUTION: @Ralph actually that was the mistake, query was poorly constructed. This would be the new query:  `@Query("SELECT new com.raquel.tfg.web.rest.dto.CitaDTO(c.empleado, count(c)) from Cita c GROUP BY c.empleado ORDER BY c.fecha_hora")`. Thank you very much